# Does NLP Transformer has backpropagation and how BERT has its word embedding?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, word-embedding, transformer-model

I was reading Attention all you need papers and i have not get any idea how the weights are updated in the Transformer base architecture is there any Backpropagation ? normally yes for the model to learn and update his weights but could any one confirm me that and explain it to me if possible ?

I know about the sum up of the 3 embeddings in the input of the Transformer (sentece embedding, postional embedding and wordpiece embedding) howerver, could any one explain to me what'is exactly a wordpiece embedding ? all i know it has 30k vocabulary tokens but i did not know how it trained, is it trained by a Transformer?
Thanks !

Comment: It would be helpful to present some coding effort to be able to discuss in a more concrete basis.

Comment: i was asking about architeture, high level understanding

Comment: SO is more about specific programming question, I would suggest posting it to another community such as Data Science.

Comment: ah this is my first asked question, im new on Stackoverflow. Next time i will try to seach for the right tags

Answer (score 0):

Please find the accepted solution to the same question (ref.[1]):

> These integers, i.e. the indices of the word pieces, map into vectors using BERT’s embedding matrix (which is initialized randomly and trained during pre-training) and is 768-dimensional.

My interpretation is that bert's first layer maps the word piece indices onto word vectors. These word vectors are context insensitive and they are trained during the training of the entire modell. Then, the (pre-defined) embeddings of the positional and sentence embedding are added to the token embeddings.

Also, the pytorch Bert-models from huggingface have one additional layer, e.g. 13 instead of 12. This additional layer is the word piece embedding layer (ref. [2].

1: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/whats-the-input-of-bert/14932

2: https://mccormickml.com/2019/05/14/BERT-word-embeddings-tutorial/#word-vectors

Comment: Thank you for yur answer, it is helpfull it is clear now. do you have any idea about Backpropagation in Transformer?